# Tomcat slow reponse in HTTPS request(SSL)

Tags: java, logging, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have one situation where tomcat SSL request taking some time to respond.

My Java application hosted in tomcat and it contains web services and SSL enabled in tomcat.
Whenever request from customer, eventhough appication responding fast enough to respond but tomcat is slow in response to customer back.

possible cause is SSL Handshake happening very slow at tomcat and looks like SSL handshake happening at every request and not one time between customer and tomcat.

There javax.net.debug=ssl option to enable SSL logs, but printing logs at the start time of tomcat not on every request.
Is there any option to print SSL logs on request basis at tomcat level?

can some one help on give pointers how to solve this.

Comment: I would have expected -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to show _all_ SSL-related activity, for the life of the application. Are you sure the output isn't being suppressed somehow? The JVM writes the logging to stdout, so what happens to it depends on what Tomcat does to stdout. Could it be going to an unexpected log file? Anyway -- I'd expect a lot of SSL handshake activity, even with one client. Using HTTP 1.1 does allow connection to stay open longer than HTTP 1.0 did, those advantages are rarely realized by webservices.

Comment: A common cause of SSL handshake being slow is that random number generation is slow. This a situation that needs to be investigated for the specific platform.

Comment: Thanks for the response kevin. With  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl  command logs are printing in tomcat8-stdout.2020-09-21.log file, but in this file only on tomcat start SSL related logs printing not on request basis. I am not able to figure it out where those logs going to. If atleast handshake information printing somewhere, I can able to tell this is the place where issue is there.